# It won't display the filtered range of date in the table

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I want to get the data from the two dates in MySQL and display only the range, however even if it is blank it won't display anything. Moreover, even if I change the simple date format to `MM/dd/yyyy` the table only display one row and date even I have 2 rows in the database daated `07/14/2022`

Here is my code

```
private void table_stocks(String date_from, String date_to)  {
    try { 
        int table;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            
            if(date_from.equals("") || date_to.equals("")){
                pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `sales_number`, `date`, `amount_due` FROM `dnk_database`.`sales`;");
            }
            else{
                pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `sales_number`, `date`, `amount_due`, SUM(`amount_due`) AS `total_sales` FROM `dnk_database`.`sales` WHERE `date` BETWEEN ? AND ?;");
                pst.setString(1, date_from);
                pst.setString(2, date_to);
            }
            
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
     
            
            ResultSetMetaData rsd = rs.getMetaData();
            table = rsd.getColumnCount();
            
            DefaultTableModel load = (DefaultTableModel)jTable_salesValue.getModel();
            load.setRowCount(0);
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                Vector v2 = new Vector();
                
                for(int i = 1; i <= table; i++){
                    v2.add(rs.getString("sales_number"));
                    v2.add(rs.getString("date"));
                    v2.add(rs.getString("amount_due"));
                }
                load.addRow(v2);
            }
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Add_Items.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Add_Items.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Also, want to display the SUM of the `amount_due` column from my SQL to a textfield and I don't know where to place this code

```
if (rs.next()==true) {
    String sum_total = rs.getString("total_sales");
    jTextField_totalSales.setText(sum_total);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't really matter, as you get only one row  back from your sum query, without an `GROUP BY`, but why not add it to the vektor and then you can assign it after you grabbed the data

Comment: Configure a prepared statement with `LocalDate` objects using the `setObject` and `getObject` methods in JDBC 4.2 and later. This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow, so search to learn more.

Comment: By the way, we’ve not needed to call `Class.forName` to load JDBC drivers for many years. JDBC was improved to auto load drivers via [Java SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

Answer (score 0):

You can accumulate the sum to a variable before the while loop, I assume you are using integer data type, then inside the loop sum the value. After the while loop is done display in the text field

```
int sumTotal = 0;
while(rs.next()) {
    Vector v2 = new Vector();
    for(int i = 1; i <= table; i++){
        v2.add(rs.getString("sales_number"));
        v2.add(rs.getString("date"));
        v2.add(rs.getString("amount_due"));
        sumTotal += rs.getString("amount_due") == null? 0 : Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("amount_due"));
        }
        load.addRow(v2);
        jTextField_totalSales.setText(sumTotal);
}
```